# Display modified time without seconds

Tags: list-form, json

Trying to display modified time in a list, showing the time only in hh:mm format.

I added json as follows to column formatting, which shows hh:mm:ss -

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div", 
    "txtContent": { 
        "operator": "toLocaleTimeString()", 
        "operands": ["@currentField"] 
    } 
}
```

Tried adding formatting in the the parantheses as follows (display is blank for column if I use this json ), but then it shows nothing in that column.

```
{
    "$schema":"https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType":"div",
    "txtContent": {
        "operator":"toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'})",
        "operands":["@currentField"]
    }
}
```

Is there a format string that will work here?

Comment: is it a calculated column ? your time only column !

Comment: No, this is the Datetime 'Modified' field of a record in a SharePoint List.   Not trying to edit the contents, of course, just trying to display the time portion without showing seconds.